# Rewrite url with 2 parameters in htaccess

Tags: php, apache

```
example.com/index.php?route=pavblog/blogs&id=$2
```

I need to load this URL to

```
example.com/blogs/blogname
```

I tried in .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*) index.php?route=pavblog/blogs&id=$2
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Why the 2 in $2 ? Why not $1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want this :

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*) index.php?route=pavblog%2Fblogs&id=$1
```

I changed `$2` to `$1` (there's only one captured group) and I escaped the `/` to `%2F`.

Comment: Hi Dystroy,
Thank you so much for your answer,

But I need to load this url

example.com/index.php?route=pavblog/blogs

to be like this
example.com/blogs/

and this url
example.com/index.php?route=pavblog/blogs&id=13

to be like this
example.com/blogs/blogname

Comment: Try `/index.php` rather than just `index.php`. Sometimes that helps. Also, if you have any Query String values in the original incoming URI, you would need a [QSA] flag to preserve them. Above all, keep your terminology straight: your incoming (from the outside world) URI is /blogs/blogname, and you are converting it to a form that the server and PHP can understand: /index.php?.... Now, if the blog id can be empty (null), what do you want to happen?

Comment: How do you want /blogs/ to be handled, and in your second case, you can't do it -- it has no place to get the id from the incoming URI. All you have available to tell one blog from another is the blogname. If the blogname _included_ the id (e.g., "myblog-13" or "13/myblog") that would be possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestion, I have added the blog name with id on the url and fixed issue now.